# Natural language generation requiring every n-word to be from the feed sentence

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, steganography

For example,

Given the feed sentence:

> "The game is up. Hudson has told all. Fly for your life"

I want to create a sentence:

> "**The** supply of **game** for London **is** going steadily **up**. Head-keeper **Hudson**, we believe, **has** been now **told** to receive **all** orders for **fly**-paper and **for** preservation of **your** hen pheasant's **life**."

In other words, the generated sentence needs to contain the sequential words of the given sentence in every third word, but the rest of the sentence could be anything as long as it makes a grammatical sense.

The example is from Doyles' "The Adventure of the Gloria Scott".

My research leads me to the field of linguistic steganography, but I can't seem to find any relevant research paper for the project.

Comment: Have you tried RNNs? You could train one with some of the classic literature or wikipedia and come up with readable sentences. As for inserting your input in the middle, you can use any POS taggers on both your input and the generated sentences, replace the appropriate words as the sentence is being generated.
For example, the network might generate "The supply of candy.." but you detect candy is a "Subject" and you replace it with a Subject from your input and resume the generator based on that newly formed sentence.

Comment: I guess with that approach, I can even use simpler Markov chain generator, but given that every third words need to match the exact POS as well as not making it so out of place would make it difficult